# how can i get input from Text in tkinter in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.text

I wanted to get input from a tkinter.Text object in python

```
msg = tkinter.StringVar()
message = tkinter.Entry(mainframe, textvariable=msg)
```

but it gives an error

I also tried the get method

```
thetext = message.get('1.0', 'end')
```

but it gives this error:

```
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', index1, index2)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. The error you show ("invalid command...") happens if you try to use a widget after it has been destroyed.

Comment: you may have to copy text from Entry to other variable before you close/destroy window. But you should still have this text in `StringVar` - `msg.get()`

Answer (score 0):

When you close (destroy) window then it removes (destroys) also `Entry` (and other widgets) and you get error when you try to use `Entry`. You have to get text from `Entry` before you close (destroy) window.

OR

Because you use `StringVar` in `Entry` so you can get this text from `StringVar` even after closing (destroying) window.

---

Minimal working example which shows this problem and solutions.

```
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def on_click():
    global result

    result = entry.get()

    print('[before] result   :', result)      # OK - before destroying window
    print('[before] StringVar:', msg.get())   # OK - before destroying window
    print('[before] Entry    :', entry.get()) # OK - before destroying window

    root.destroy()

# --- main ---

result = "" # variable for text from `Entry`

root = tk.Tk()

msg = tk.StringVar(root)
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=msg)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Close', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()

# --- after closing window ---

print('[after] result   :', result)      # OK    - after destroying window
print('[after] StringVar:', msg.get())   # OK    - after destroying window
print('[after] Entry    :', entry.get()) # ERROR - after destroying window
```